# Как отследить завершение процесса и скопировать определенный файл в другую папку?

Tags: java, io

Задача возникла такая:
1) Отследить, когда закроется определенная программа (процесс)
2) После завершения программы (или процесса) создается файл, его нужно скопировать в другую директорию (название файла известно)
Пока что я не знаю как сделать ни то, ни другое. Хотелось бы узнать примерную реализацию сие задач.

Comment: какая операционная система?

Comment: Операционная система Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно узнать список процессов, как пропадет из списка ваш это можно узнать например через `String.contains()` выполняете перенос файла. Естественно для этого нужно создать поток `new Tread` или `new Runnable` в котором будет запрашиваться таск лист с какой-то периодичностью.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            String line;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist");
            BufferedReader input =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line); //<-- Parse data here.
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```